# Inheritance of Dart packages

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance, package

I use the flutter library [`rflutter_alert`](https://pub.dev/packages/rflutter_alert) to show an alert (view code). But I want the buttons to show as a `TextButton` and not a `DialogButton`. I tought I could fix this problem by using inheritance in another class `MyPopupAlert` and than use this class instead of `Alert(...)` but I don't know how to implement this...

I showed my try at the bottom.

Thanks

```
_addPopup(context) {
    Alert(
        context: context,
        title: "LOGIN",
        content: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                labelText: 'Username',
              ),
            ),
            TextField(
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.lock),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        buttons: [
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "LOGIN",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DialogButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
            child: Text(
              "LOGIN",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.blue,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]).show();
  }
```

```
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyPopupAlert extends Alert {
  MyPopupAlert({List<TextButton> buttons});
}
```

Comment: Unless the class is pluggable in the framework you want to use, you're mostly out of luck.  Nothing you can type can keep it from calling the existing Alert() class constructor.

Comment: Oke, I will try something else, thanks for responding!